# MemoryMappedFile causes next File.Open to take long time

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I'm playing around with accessing large files by using memory mapped files. While researching the performance in comparison with standard I/O file access mechanisms I noticed an unusual behavior which I currently cannot explain. 
After accessing a 3GB large file with a memory map with the `MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite` flag it takes about 9 seconds to open the file again, even if I just open a `FileStream` on the file. The next access to the file after using the `MemoryMappedFile` will be slow. This happens even without having ViewAccessors defined, without writing anything to the file. If I create the MemoryMappedFile with the `Read` flag, this behavior does not occur and the next open operation will only take about a millisecond.

I read that dirty pages might not get written to disk until the map is no longer in use but considering I do not write anything to the file and the process is the only one using the memory map I do not understand why this still happens.

I tested with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestFileOpen();
    TestMMF();
    TestMMF();
    TestFileOpen();
    TestFileOpen();
    TestMMF();

    Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void TestMMF()
{
    Console.Write("Open Memory Mapped File... ");
    const long size = 1024L*1024L*3000L;

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(stream, "Map", size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, null, HandleInheritability.None, true))
    {
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}

private static void TestFileOpen()
{
    Console.Write("Open File Stream...        ");

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    using (File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Which gives me:

```
Open File Stream...        9,2946138
Open Memory Mapped File... 0,0003105
Open Memory Mapped File... 9,2050714
Open File Stream...        9,2130051
Open File Stream...        0,0001751
Open Memory Mapped File... 0,0001529
Finished.
```

Note that the call after using FileStream will be fast and the call after using a MemoryMappedFile will take long.
Also note that the first call also takes long which is because the last call in the benchmark program (of the previous run of the application!) accessed the file with a memory map.

Am I missing something? Can I do something to prevent this?

Comment: Is this all code? Are you not writing anything? Capture a procmon.exe trace of these operations. There's a duration column. Let's see what exactly takes so much time.

Comment: @usr Yes, that is the code that is executed. Good call on the process monitor. The recurring lines with long durations look like this: 
`[...] CreateFile [...] SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0, OpenResult: Opened 9.3067812`
Where 9.3067812 is the duration.

Comment: According to procmon no other process accesses the file. However I executed the application on another machine and it's running without problems there. I have a feeling that it might have something to do with software like virus scanners on my development machine...

Comment: You can try to run PerfView to profile the machine during the delays. The CPU stacks view might show who is on the stack. Maybe you'll find AV there. You need to look at the System process and at your own.

Comment: I see no evidence for this at all, not even on a 8 GB file.  Opening the file takes 10 msec, the rest takes less than a msec.  Nor does it make any sense, it is not the way Windows works.  But it is forever bogged down by the crapware, disable your anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: Yes! I see that mcshield.exe (McAffee On Access scanner) is reading the file during the entire execution. That's probably it. Now I have to find a way to work around that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As determined in the comments this delay is caused by Anti Virus software.